# Deleting on laravel via confirmation message modal?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to delete something via jquery using my url on routes, I have this but ain't working dunno why

routes.php

```
Route::delete('/administrar/invitacion/{id}', 'invitacionController@eliminarInvitacion');
```

on my administrar.blade.php I have a select where i retrieve the id and this modal with two buttons

```
<!-- Modal borrar -->
                                                <div class="modal fade" id="borrar" role="dialog">
                                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                                        <!-- Modal content-->
                                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                                                <h4 class="modal-title">Borrar invitación</h4>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                                <p>¿Estás seguro que quieres cancelar esta invitación?</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                                <button type="button" id="delete_invite" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Si</button>
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
```

invitacionController.php

```
public function eliminarInvitacion(Request $request, Invite $invite)
    {
        $this->authorize('destroy', $invite);

        $invite->delete();

        return redirect('/administrar');
    }
```

on my js:

```
  $('#borrar').on('click', '#delete_invite', function(e) {

        $id = $( "#selectinv option:selected" ).val();
        $.ajax({url: "/administrar/invitacion/"+$id, type: 'DELETE', success: function(result){


        }});
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting without a form, just had to add this before my button

```
<input type="hidden" id="token" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

then on js my example:

```
$('#borrar').on('click', '#delete_invite', function(e) {
    //Declaration
    var token = $('#token').val();
    var id = $( "#selectinv option:selected" ).val();

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    //Delete request
    $.ajax({
        type:   'DELETE',
        url:    '/administrar/invitacion/' + id,
        data:   { _token :token },
        success: function(data){
             window.location="/administrar";
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not work since you are using `Route::delete`and you're not posting a CSRF token. To make this work, you either have to change your route to `Route::get`, or post a CSRF token.

To read more about this, see https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection.

Also, if you have no idea why ajax calls are not working, open your console, then hit the "Network" tab, and then do your ajax request. The request will appear on the bottom, and then u can get details if you click on it.

Comment: Tought I only had to use {{ csrf_field() }} and {{ method_field('DELETE') }} on forms, but i'm not using any form here, just a button with an ID, I edited my post with the entire modal so you can check it better, so I have to create a form with csrf or how?

Comment: When you don't use forms, you can only do GET requests (as far as I know). When deleting, patching, putting or storing you have to use a form with a csrf token.

Comment: If you want to do this with ajax and with a DELETE request, just create a form with a {{ csrf_field() }} and the invitacion id. Then when the #borrar button is clicked, `submit()` the form and do an ajax request with `data: $(theForm).serialize();`.